# Поиск альтернативы @DataProvider java на python

Tags: python

Пробуем перейти с java на python, возникли проблемы с поиском альтернативы DataProvider. Используется для создания списка url и использования для параллели тестов.

```
public class TextAds {
    @DataProvider(name = "toolsTextAds")
    public static Object[][] toolsTextAds() {
        return new Object[][]{
{new ToolsBannerWithSrc1}
{new ToolsBannerWithSrc2}
{new ToolsBannerWithSrc3}
{new ToolsBannerWithSrc4}
{new ToolsBannerWithSrc5}
 };
 }
}
```

Результатом является очень приятное и понятное отображение в IDE

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос в том, возможно ли сделать такое же на python v3.9?

Comment: А чем не удобен unittest, который из коробки? С java не работал, объясните. С помощью него в основном пишут тесты и запускают файлы

Comment: @Georgiy, извините за долгий ответ. Не нашел способа распараллелить тесты в юниттесте. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как там это сделать?